# Defining plot theme as a function of two parameters

Tags: plotting

I would like to define a new `PlotTheme` as a function of two variables `{x,y}`, how can I do that? 
Here is my try:

```
Themes`AddThemeRules["mysty", 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, 
FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[x]}], Frame -> True, 
FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Thickness[y]], 
 Directive[White, Thickness[y]]}, {Directive[Black, Thickness[y]],
  Directive[White, Thickness[y]]}}];
With[{x = 0.005, y = 0.007}, 
Plot[{Sin[z], Cos[z]}, {z, 0, 7}, PlotTheme -> "mysty"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new theme using `` System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme ``:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"mysty2", x_Real, y_Real}, _] :=
 {LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[x]}], 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black,Thickness[y]],  Directive[White,Thickness[y]]}, 
   {Directive[Black,Thickness[y]], Directive[White, Thickness[y]]}}}
```

***Examples:***

```
Plot[{Sin[z], Cos[z]}, {z, 0, 7}, PlotTheme -> {"mysty2", 0.005, .01}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[z Cos[z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotTheme -> {"mysty2", 0.005, .007}, FrameStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @kglr, is it possible to generalize it for `DensityPlot`  and `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @HD2006, if you replace `"Plot"`  with  `_`  the new theme should work with any plotting/charting function that has `PlotTheme` as an option.